# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException while opening netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

Whenever i starts the netbeans, i am getting this error `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException`, i am not understanding why it is coming contiguously , previously i was working a project and i used `servlet` and `hibernate framework`, which runs well at that time but now this errors comes continuously

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
at java.nio.StringCharBuffer.subSequence(StringCharBuffer.java:92)
at org.netbeans.modules.java.editor.javadoc.JavadocCompletionUtils.isLineBreak(JavadocCompletionUtils.java:325)
at org.netbeans.modules.java.editor.javadoc.JavadocCompletionUtils.isLineBreak(JavadocCompletionUtils.java:306)
at org.netbeans.modules.java.editor.javadoc.DocPositions.resolve(DocPositions.java:177)
```

**Caused:**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Please attach dump file file:/C:/Users/praveen/AppData/Roaming/NetBeans/7.3beta2/var/log/Servlet_163.jddump to bug.
at org.netbeans.modules.java.editor.javadoc.JavadocCompletionUtils.dumpOutOfSyncError(JavadocCompletionUtils.java:522)
at org.netbeans.modules.java.editor.javadoc.JavadocCompletionUtils.dumpOutOfSyncError(JavadocCompletionUtils.java:594)
at org.netbeans.modules.java.editor.javadoc.DocPositions.resolve(DocPositions.java:209)
```

**Caused:**
`java.lang.IllegalStateException:` '
 @author praveen
'

```
org.netbeans.modules.java.editor.javadoc.DocPositions@3ecc02
```

**token sequence dump:**
TokenSequence for `text/x-java/text/x-javadoc at tokenIndex=1`. TokenList contains 5 tokens:

```
T[0]: "\n *\n * " <484,491> OTHER_TEXT[5] DefT, IHC=32569212
*[1]: "@author" <491,498> TAG[1] DefT, IHC=17308677
T[2]: " " <498,499> OTHER_TEXT[5] DefT, IHC=23575283
T[3]: "praveen" <499,506> IDENT[0] DefT, IHC=19063215
T[4]: "\n " <506,508> OTHER_TEXT[5] DefT, IHC=17748422

at org.netbeans.modules.java.editor.javadoc.DocPositions.resolve(DocPositions.java:212)
at org.netbeans.modules.java.editor.javadoc.DocPositions.getTags(DocPositions.java:138)
at org.netbeans.modules.java.editor.javadoc.JavadocImports.computeReferencedElements(JavadocImports.java:123)
at org.netbeans.modules.java.editor.imports.UnusedImports$DetectorVisitor.handleJavadoc(UnusedImports.java:137)
at org.netbeans.modules.java.editor.imports.UnusedImports$DetectorVisitor.visitClass(UnusedImports.java:144)
at org.netbeans.modules.java.editor.imports.UnusedImports$DetectorVisitor.visitClass(UnusedImports.java:116)
at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCClassDecl.accept(JCTree.java:620)
at com.sun.source.util.TreePathScanner.scan(TreePathScanner.java:67)
at org.netbeans.api.java.source.support.CancellableTreePathScanner.scan(CancellableTreePathScanner.java:94)
at com.sun.source.util.TreeScanner.scan(TreeScanner.java:90)
at org.netbeans.api.java.source.support.CancellableTreePathScanner.scan(CancellableTreePathScanner.java:103)
at org.netbeans.modules.java.editor.imports.UnusedImports$DetectorVisitor.visitCompilationUnit(UnusedImports.java:171)
at org.netbeans.modules.java.editor.imports.UnusedImports$DetectorVisitor.visitCompilationUnit(UnusedImports.java:116)
at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCCompilationUnit.accept(JCTree.java:490)
at com.sun.source.util.TreePathScanner.scan(TreePathScanner.java:67)
at org.netbeans.api.java.source.support.CancellableTreePathScanner.scan(CancellableTreePathScanner.java:94)
at org.netbeans.modules.java.editor.imports.UnusedImports.process(UnusedImports.java:94)
at org.netbeans.modules.java.editor.semantic.SemanticHighlighter.computeUnusedImports(SemanticHighlighter.java:135)
at org.netbeans.modules.java.hints.Imports.unusedImport(Imports.java:97)
```

**Caused:** `java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException`

```
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
[catch] at org.netbeans.modules.java.hints.providers.code.CodeHintProviderImpl$WorkerImpl.createErrors(CodeHintProviderImpl.java:299)
at org.netbeans.modules.java.hints.spiimpl.hints.HintsInvoker.runHint(HintsInvoker.java:751)
at org.netbeans.modules.java.hints.spiimpl.hints.HintsInvoker.access$300(HintsInvoker.java:110)
at org.netbeans.modules.java.hints.spiimpl.hints.HintsInvoker$ScannerImpl.runAndAdd(HintsInvoker.java:618)
at org.netbeans.modules.java.hints.spiimpl.hints.HintsInvoker$ScannerImpl.scan(HintsInvoker.java:656)
at org.netbeans.modules.java.hints.spiimpl.hints.HintsInvoker.computeHintsImpl(HintsInvoker.java:250)
at org.netbeans.modules.java.hints.spiimpl.hints.HintsInvoker.computeHints(HintsInvoker.java:233)
at org.netbeans.modules.java.hints.spiimpl.hints.HintsInvoker.computeHints(HintsInvoker.java:204)
at org.netbeans.modules.java.hints.spiimpl.hints.HintsInvoker.computeHints(HintsInvoker.java:180)
at org.netbeans.modules.java.hints.spiimpl.hints.HintsInvoker.computeHints(HintsInvoker.java:147)
at org.netbeans.modules.java.hints.spiimpl.hints.HintsTask.run(HintsTask.java:113)
at org.netbeans.modules.java.hints.spiimpl.hints.HintsTask.run(HintsTask.java:83)
at org.netbeans.modules.java.source.JavaSourceAccessor$CancelableTaskWrapper.run(JavaSourceAccessor.java:298)
at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.TaskProcessor.callParserResultTask(TaskProcessor.java:559)
at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.TaskProcessor$CompilationJob.run(TaskProcessor.java:735)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Comment: this is too much code too less detail on the problem.

Comment: Close Netbeans, delete this folder `C:/Users/praveen/AppData/Roaming/NetBeans`, start Netbeans again.

Comment: Have you closed the javadoc in the mentioned file? Is it possible, you use a different line ending in the `@author praveen` line?

Comment: I know its too much but for better understanding of my problem i had uploaded it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that if you rollback more changes and those changes are conflicting (affect the same code) svn creates a
file with nested conflict blocks that cannot be easily resolved. Maybe the conflicts resolver could detect that and show
a message instead that you need to resolve this manually in the editor.

check [link](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=135542)